# How do I Add-Migration after deleting the existing database WITHOUT closing existing connections?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, web

In my ASP.NET Core Web application I initially migrated to a database which I have now deleted. In the process I forgot to tab "Close existing connections". Ever since I haven't been able to Add-Migration.

PM after "Add-Migration": 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Usually deleting the existing database and closing existing connections works, but now I only deleted the database  without closing existing connections.

Are there any solution to this problem?

[Package Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhDoI.png)

Comment: Just do one thing keep backup of existing migrations from the root folder migration in project. And after removing recent migrations. Then again run the Add migration

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately without any difference.

Comment: Could you please show stack trace with inner exception

Comment: I added a screenshot of the Package Manager Console during Add-Migration. I hope that's what you meant. Sorry in advance I am new to programming.

Comment: Your issue is happening because of two different versions of entity framework conflict in your project. Please do one thing, Go to the Nuget manager (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for solution). 

And uninstall the entity framework core if you dont want to use core version and want to use entity framework version. Either you can remove entity framework 6.x version if you want to use entityframework core version.

Comment: By doing Add-Migration after uninstalling EntityFramework in Nuget Package Manager I get the message: The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'ProjectName'. If I uninstall the EF core I will get the same initial result.

Comment: There should be atleast one in your project entity framewor 6.x or entity framework core.